# can single xml file be linked to multiple java classes?

Tags: java, android, xml

can we link a single XML file to multiple java files in android.
i am using eclipse as IDE.
i have three image button for date, time in & time out. I have java classes to have a single XML containing the functions.

Comment: are u sure because m not able to only my main class containing the calender function is working. but the classes containing function time in and time out not working.

Comment: m not talking about android manifest file i am talking about a simple xml containing my design

Comment: Improve you question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can have one layout XML file and use the same layout in different activities. All you have to do is to use the same layout id in `setContentView()` method.

The same applies to fragments.